# GTK3 : How to exclude particular area in GtkTextView in GTk3 c

Tags: c, textview, gtk3

I am working on the Gtk3 application in c, I wanted to add an image on top of a big paragraph like this, and the paragraph contents will wrap around the image accordingly to the visible area

[image]

I found that we can add images inside GtkTextView with [gtk_text_buffer_insert_pixbuf](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.TextBuffer.insert_pixbuf.html), but doing this will increase the height of the whole line like this, as the image is considered as a single character.

[image]

When we place the image on top of the TextView, is there any way where we can exclude that particular area so that, the text which should have been below the area of the overlapped image will come on the next visible area? is there any way to do this

Thank you